# bash script creating virtual filesystem and mounting it on a specific directory

Tags: php, linux, bash, debian-buster

here is my problem: i would like to create a directory and limit it size using this [method](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/directory-quota-601140/).

The thing is when i try it via **cli** its working perfectly (the file system is mounted on the newly created directory with its size limit), however when i put it in a bash script the directory is created but not with its size limit.

Here is my *script.sh*:

```
# !/bin/bash


# Set default parameters
limited_directory_name=$1
size=$2

# Setting path
parent_path="/path/to/directory/parent/"
directory_path="$parent_path$limited_directory_name"

# Creating directory/mountpoint
mkdir "$directory_path"

#Creating a file full of /dev/zero
limited_size_file="$directory_path.ext4"
touch "$limited_size_file"
dd if=/dev/zero of="$limited_size_file" bs="$size" count=1

#Formating the file
sudo mkfs.ext4 "$limited_size_file"

#Mount the disk
sudo mount -o loop,rw,usrquota,grpquota "$limited_size_file" "$directory_path"
```

I believe (pretty sure actually), that the problem is in these two last lines

`sudo mkfs.ext4 "$limited_size_file"`

or/and

`sudo mount -o loop,rw,usrquota,grpquota "$limited_size_file" "$directory_path"`

because as i said, the file and directory are created but just not with the size limit.

Also when i try to delete the directory ($directory_path/) after executing those command via **cli** i got : `rm: cannot delete '$directory_path/': Device or resource busy`, that i dont get when trying to delete it after executing the script. So i guess that the file system is not mounted when executing the script, and the problem is probably in the last two lines. I dont know if its has something to do with the way of using **sudo** inside a script or just something with mounting a file system inside a bash script.

I just wanna say that i am fairly new to bash scripting and i am sorry if my mistake is something like an obvious (noob) error. You can also say if i can improve my question in any way and i apologize if it's not clear enough.

And one last thing, i have tried different syntax for the last two line like:

`sudo $(mkfs.ext4 "$limited_size_file")`

or

```
sudo `mkfs.ext4 "$limited_size_file"`
```

or just

`mkfs.ext4 "$limited_size_file"` without sudo.

But nothing seems to work. I am using debian 10 btw and im calling the script like this in a PHP page (if it can help):

```
exec("myscript.sh $dname $dsize");
```

Comment: The only syntax issue I see is the space between # and ! `#!/bin/bash`, not `# !/bin/bash`.  That aside.   When you `try it via cli` ... do you run the PHP script from cli, or the shell script? As which user do you do it? Same user as the one running the PHP script when it gets executed by the web-server?

Comment: Imagine if this worked. Just running `sudo` from a PHP page and getting instant root access to everything without a password.

Comment: =D @thatotherguy ... wouldn't that be great ;)

Comment: @thatotherguy im still new sorry, what should i do different? And btw this is only for testing and learning purpose on my localhost and will not go on any production server

Comment: @tink i meant typing each command one by one in cli. When i try to execute the script from cli it still creates both the file and the folder without mounting it and plus those errors: `mkfs.ext4 : command not found` and `mount : only root can use « --options » option`

Comment: And as which user? You may want to edit your question with the extra info, btw, rather than leaving it in the comments... as for the "command not found" - either use the fully qualified path, or add `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` to your `PATH` ... I'd recommend method 1.